# Flutter About using Mediaquery

Tags: flutter, flutter-responsive-layout

**I have a quetion : is it a good practice to use Mediaquery for all kind of dimentions, I mean for padding,margin, border , When I should use and When I should use some fixed Values**

Comment: When you want  UI to be `responsive` it will  be a good practice to use `Mediaquery` for all kind of dimentions.

Comment: No.  Check out this summary by Pixeltoast on the fundamentals of Flutter layout including MediaQuery: https://notes.tst.sh/flutter/media-query/